# Service Broker : Sys.Conversation_endpoints filling up with CO/CONVERSING messages when using With Cleanup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service, service-broker

We recently identified a problem with one of our databases where as a result of a 'fire & forget' setup (i.e: conversations being closed immediately after sending), our sys.conversation_endpoints table was filling up with DI/DISCONNECTED_INBOUND messages. This eventually spilled over into the tempDB, causing it to grow enormously and eat up precious disk space. We eventually resolved this issue by commenting out the line

`END CONVERSATION @handle WITH CLEANUP`

in our sending SP and closing the conversations in our receiving SP using the same code,

`END CONVERSATION @handle WITH CLEANUP`

However, we now have a new issue. Since moving servers (and migrating from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008) we've recently discovered that sys.conversation_endpoints is now filling up with CO/CONVERSING messages, indicating that the conversations are not being closed. The receiving SP is closing them, or at least is running the command to do so, so I don't understand where these messages are coming from.

I've tried going back to ending the conversation at the point of send, but it has no effect. Is it wrong to end conversations on the receiving end using `WITH CLEANUP`? Or is there some other problem?

This [post on techtarget](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/service-broker-may-not-remove-messages-after-processing/) seems to suggest its a bug, and that running a job to cleanup the leftovers is the only solution...

UPDATE: 
Pawel pointed out below that I should be avoiding the Fire & Forget Pattern, and I've added an activated SP to the initiator queue to end any conversations. However, sys.conversation_endpoints is STILL filling up, this time with CD/CLOSED messages. Here's the structure of my queues

Send_SP:

```
DECLARE @h UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @h 
FROM SERVICE 'InitiatorQueue' TO SERVICE 'TargetQueue' 
ON CONTRACT 'MyContract' WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF; 
SEND ON CONVERSATION @h MESSAGE TYPE 'MyMessage' (@msg)
```

Receive_SP (Activated SP on TargetQueue)

```
DECLARE @type SYSNAME, @h UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @msg XML;
DECLARE @target TABLE (
    [message_type_name] SYSNAME,
    [message_body] VARBINARY(MAX),
    [conversation_handle] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP (1000) 
        [message_type_name],[message_body],[conversation_handle] 
        FROM TargetQueue INTO @target), TIMEOUT 2000            
    IF(@@rowcount!=0)
    BEGIN
        WHILE((SELECT count(*) FROM @target) > 0) 
        BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (1) @type = [message_type_name],
            @msg = [message_body],
            @h = [conversation_handle]  FROM @target;
        // Handle Message Here
        END CONVERSATION @h; 
        DELETE TOP (1) FROM @target;
    END
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

End_SP (Activated SP on InitiatorQueue)

```
DECLARE @type SYSNAME, @h UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @msg XML;
DECLARE @init TABLE (
    [message_type_name] SYSNAME,
    [message_body] VARBINARY(MAX),
    [conversation_handle] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP (1000) 
        [message_type_name],[message_body],[conversation_handle] 
        FROM InitiatorQueue INTO @init), TIMEOUT 2000           
    IF(@@rowcount!=0)
    BEGIN
        WHILE((SELECT count(*) FROM @init) > 0) 
        BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (1) @type = [message_type_name],
            @msg = [message_body],
            @h = [conversation_handle]  FROM @init;
        END CONVERSATION @h; 
        DELETE TOP (1) FROM @init;
    END
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the fire-and-forget pattern will inevitably lead to this and other types of issues. Additionally it will make any hypothetical errors go unnoticed. Is there any reason why you can't change the message exchange pattern so that the target issues END CONVERSATION (without cleanup!) once it receives a message and then the initiator only calls END CONVERSATION (again, without cleanup) upon receiving end conversation message from the target?

Comment: Hi Pawel, I can certainly remove the WITH CLEANUP I've been using, you think that's causing a problem? 

I understand that the pattern I'm using is not the best, but it suits the type of service we have.

Comment: When you say that the fire-and-forget pattern suits the type of service you have, you implicitly acknowledge that the inherent problems of fire-and-forget also suit the type of service. In other words, you're saying that you're OK with conversation_endpoints filling up, lost messages and missed errors. I personally don't believe that any type of service (at least not any I'd like to use) should be OK with these things and that's why I recommended dropping the fire-and-forget approach. But in the end of course the choice is yours.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I didn't fully understand. We currently have a system which sends one-way messages from an asp.net app to a database via a service broker queue. The receiving activated procedure uses a table variable, and pulls 1000 messages from the queue at a time, processing and ending each one. Because of this, messages can stay in the queue for a few seconds.

I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that changing the initiator to also listen for the end conversations of these messages would put a serious lag on the system (ie. a few seconds per request), is this not accurate?

Comment: Just realised I can put an activated sp on the initiator queue too, which would negate any delay issues of course. Doh. Unfortunately it's still not working - I'm updating the question now

Comment: The conversation endpoints on the target side should stay around for some time after the conversation is ended (in CLOSED state). This is a security measure and is by design. However, they should go away after approximately 30 minutes. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: I'll leave them for a little over 30 minutes and see if the number levels off

Comment: @PawelMarciniak "However, they should go away after approximately 30 minutes" means the value of "lifeTime"? I see a very big value in our sys.conversation_endpoints says "2079-11-28 10:43:35.810"...

Comment: @roryok What's your sql server version? Looks MS fixed in sp4. See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835760/enddialog-messages-stuck-in-target-transmission-queue-with-conversation-endpoint)