# EndDialog Messages stuck in TARGET transmission queue with conversation endpoint in DISCONNECTED_OUTBOUND state

Tags: sql-server, service, service-broker

EndDialog messages are stuck in the TARGET(remote) transmission queue. The transmission_status is blank on each entry.

The Initiator is actually receiving the EndDialog message and ending the dialog on it's side.

I know that for sure because I have put a PRINT on the INITIATOR service reply queue procedure. The log shows that those procedure are getting executed as a result of the INITIATOR receiving an EndDialog message.

Everything works except that in the TARGET, conversation endpoint entries remain in DO state and the EndDialog message also remains in the TARGET transmission queue.

It looks like the TARGET is not getting an ACK from the INITIATOR for the enddialog message.

On the TARGET the BROKER:CONVERSATION trace shows STARTED_INBOUND, CONVERSING, DISCONNECTED_OUTBOUND states.

Follow configuration:

TARGET: Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard 64 edition SP2, SQL Server 2008 SP2, Standard Edition 64-bit, database in compatibility mode 100

INITIATOR: Windows XP SP2,  SQL Server 2005 express SP2, Database in compatibility mode 80.

Do you have any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You don't, by any chance, end conversation WITH CLEANUP on the initiator, do you?

Comment: @Pawel: No, I am not doing that. It's a well closed loop. Like I said, the interesting thing is that the Target enddialog message does reach the Initiator and get processed but the Target does not get rid of the conversation and entries on transmission queue on its side. I have followed Remus's link http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/, and many others, but no luck so far. Messages just keep piling up on the Target side.

Comment: I see. If I were you I would collect profiler events from both servers (everything from broker category + audit broker conversation and audit broker login). Historically, a detailed analysis of these profiler traces allowed me to troubleshoot any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading SQL Server Express from SP2 to SP4 solved the issue. 
No more enddialog messages stuck on the Target transmission queue.

The Initiator was receiving and processing the enddialog messages but for some reason
the Target was not receiving an "ack". It was all very upsetting as everything else was working fine.

Before upgrading I ran all sorts of tests on database, computer and network.
The configuration appeared to be all right even after many desk reviews.

I started suspecting that upgrading would solve the issue after I deployed the same
configuration on a test machine with SQL Server Express SP4 that ran without incidents.

It just took a long time to get approval to upgrade on a production server, but now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Give [ssbdiagnose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx) a try. If your problem is related to security configuration (it most likely is), there's a big chance the diagnostic tool will point it out.